# Convert elements in an array into integer type

Tags: reactjs

```
let datas = "1,5,8,4,6"
```

I want to convert this datas into an array. I use split operator like,

```
datas.split(",")
```

But the value is in string type Iwant it in integer format. Like,

```
 datas=[1,5,8,4,6]
```

How to covert elements into integer

Comment: updated my qusetion

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert a string to an integer in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1133770/how-to-convert-a-string-to-an-integer-in-javascript)

Comment: It doesn't help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works like charm

```js
let datas = "1,5,8,4,6"
console.log(datas.split(",").map(elem => Number(elem)))
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `map` function which creates a new array populated with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array. Read more about map at [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

The `number` method (Read about it at [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_number.asp)) converts a value to a number.

```js
const datas = "1,5,8,4,6";
const arr = datas.split(",").map(d => Number(d));
console.log(arr);
```

Also as suggested by user @bogdanoff, `map(d => +d)` can also be used to convert a string value to number.

```js
const datas = "1,5,8,4,6";
const arr = datas.split(",").map(d => +d);
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: ```.map(d => +d)```  is enough, `Number(d)` returns Object  but `+d` gives primitive type

Comment: Thanks @bogdanoff, I've added your comment as answer.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```js
let datas = "1,5,8,4,6"
datas.split(",")

for (let i=0; i<datas.length; i++){
datas[i] = Number(datas[i])
}
```